# RShiny: Pass in a FilePath

Tags: r, file, shiny, path

Trying to do something pretty simple here.. I just want to hard code a file path and pass it into "read.csv" but on run it's removing the "\t" from the string.

```
filePath = toString("C:\test.csv")
scenario_data <<- read.csv(filePath, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Error:

```
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:  est.csv': Invalid argument
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
  1: runApp
```

I know in Python I can use `r"this is a string"` so that this doesn't happen. Is there something similar in RShiny?

Comment: You need to escape your backslash. `filePath = toString("C:\\test.csv")`.

Comment: @Limey I just changed the \ to / and that worked as well when I was rage coding, but I like your method better. Thanks!

Comment: These issues are best avoided using `file.path`, which takes care of path separators for you: `file.path("C:", "test.csv")`. It is OS-independent, though that advantage is slightly moot when your path starts with `C:`.